# WebView - Requesting desktop site always redirect to mobile site

Tags: android, webview, desktop

Am trying to load the desktop website in `webview` with custom user agent, but the website always detect me that am coming from mobile so they redirect me to mobile site.

I am using the below code:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

 webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted.." + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted.." + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("WebView", "onLoadResource.." + url);
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("shouldOverrideUrlLoading :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("https://xxxxxxxx.com");
```

Comment: I cannot see why you've removed the code from this question - it is probably not on-topic as it stands, as it is too brief, and appears to lack research.

Comment: As per your other rollback, I believe your last edit materially harms thiis question, so I have rolled it back. Please ping me at `@halfer` before editing this again, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
```

Try this maybe this can solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for that, you have to add and set UserAgentString to WebView settings.

For that, I have created one method from which we can enable and disable desktop view into WebView.

Call this method by passing WebView and boolean true if you want to set desktop view in your WebView.

```
public void setDesktopMode(WebView webView,boolean enabled) {
    String newUserAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    if (enabled) {
        try {
            String ua = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
            String androidOSString = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().substring(ua.indexOf("("), ua.indexOf(")") + 1);
        newUserAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace(androidOSString, "(X11; Linux x86_64)");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        newUserAgent = null;
    }

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webView.reload();
}
```

Comment: its not working its directly showing the mobile site, Even my code showing the desktop site first time second time only it showing the mobile